# Apple MusicKit JS: how to play full song, instead of preview?

Tags: apple-musickit

o/

Configured app, enabled Apple Music subscription, authorized that user in my web app, and whenever I play a song from media queue, I hear only preview playing, not the full song. When I authorize the same way on Apple Music webiste, it plays full song.

I'm developing on localhost, but all cookies and localstorage items are set, so authorization won't pop up after refresh.

Am I missing some magic param I need to pass to API in order to play full song?

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue? I've run into the same issue. Thanks.